# Getting duplicate results from unique filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of data consisting of a lot of information regarding processes. For example I want to filter out all the unique error codes that are in the data and all unique activities. I try to do so via the following routine.
Overall I'm happy with the result, but the first entry of my data is always duplicated. What am I doing wrong?

[see what the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYzDq.png)

```
Sub Test()
Dim Rohdaten_rows, Rohdaten_columns As Long
    Rohdaten_rows = Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Worksheets("Test").Columns("C:Z").EntireColumn.Delete


    Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 4) = "Unique Aktivitäten"
    Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 6) = "Unique BuHi"
    Worksheets("Test").Range("A2:A" & Rohdaten_rows).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Test").Range("D2"), unique:=True
    Worksheets("Test").Range("B2:B" & Rohdaten_rows).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Test").Range("F2"), unique:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: All filters assume a header row, so if row 2 is the start of your actual data, it's being treated as a header, and gets duplicated.

Comment: So if I cut off the first result each time or add a spare row (= empty header) I should be good to go, right?

Comment: Just include row 1, surely?

Comment: Yeah of course, I forgot to mention that. Thanks for your help!